# Permission issue running .exe from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

We have a .exe which we need to execute at the time an order is placed on a website. When 
we test this locally it works fine using IIS Express. When we move it to IIS, it fails. We assume this is a permissions error as if we set the App Pool to run as the administrator then the script works again. The question we have is how do we execute the .exe as the administrator whilst the App Pool is ApplicationIdentity? We are using the following code:

```
var process = new Process
                          {
                              StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                                              {
                                                  FileName = executablePath,
                                                  Arguments = argumentList,
                                                  Domain = domain,
                                                  UserName = userName,
                                                  Password = securePassword,
                                                  UseShellExecute = false,
                                                  LoadUserProfile = true
                                              }
                          };

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

The .exe is trying to write to the Users AppData folder which is why it fails. It is a 3rd party app so we cannot change the source code.

EDIT: Just to clarify also, when we specify the username and password in procmon it still appears to run from ISUR.

Comment: Move the job out into a seperate service and connect the web ui with the service with MSMQ. Then the service can launch the .exe without the problems associated with doing it from IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this by enabling User profile on IIS AppPool and setting permission for the IIS user on the folder it was trying to write to.

We sue ProcMon to find where the program was failing and the folder it was trying towrite to was C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

Answer (score 0):

i dont remember actually, but one of them is working 100% ( i had this issue before)

just let me know ehich one of them is the correct one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Royi, thanks for the reply. Like I said in my initial post if we set the AppPool as the Admin user then it runs fine. However, isn't setting the apppool to run as an admin dangerous?

Comment: of course its dangerous , so open a dedicated account for this task and  set the precise permissions. ( admin was just a test to eliminate use permission)

Comment: Ah in that case then yes, it does work setting the AppPool as an admin. Are you suggesting we create a user with Iusr permissions but a 'real' user and then setting it that way?